# Update process CUBE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas

I am using the SSIS Analysis task to process CUBE using the update only process.

The source records is a transactional TYPE 1, so when we get an update records to exisitng records in the source will delete and insert the new records, here Update process cube failing due to missing key at source(which is due to deleting the source records on updated source)

```
source table records            cube process records
         1000                       1000
deleted 5 and inserted 5 new        5    and key error while processing the cube.
```

we could use FULL PROCESS to avoid this problem but having performance hit,

How to do this process using the update process only.

thanks

prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quickfix could be done in analysis services deployment

- Select Process>Change Settings…> Dimension key errors
- Choose Use custom error configuration
- In Stop on Error, ensure that On Error Action is set to "Stop Logging".
- In Specific error conditions make sure that "Report and Continue" is selected.
- Click OK and the cube will be reprocessed ignoring this error.

Answer (score 0):

If there are deleted records in the source table, you have to process the cube/measure group/partition using full mode.